# Ocelot post request not going through

Tags: .net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, ocelot

I have implemented Ocelot API gateway in my project which was working fine for 'GET' requests but when I tried to send 'POST' request I am getting the error:

> previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnableToFindDownstreamRouteError Message: Failed to match ReRoute configuration for upstream path: /api/patient/CreateAppointment, verb: POST. errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path:/api/patient/CreateAppointment, request method: POST

Following is my ocelot.json:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/patient/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "patientservice",
          "Port": 81
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/patient/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST" ],
      "UpstreamHost": "*"
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/actor",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "postgresqldapper",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/actor",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "productservice",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/{everything}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/weatherforecast",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "postgresqldapper",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/weatherforecast",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "loginservicedapr",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/{everything}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "loginservicedapr",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/user/{id}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "OcRequestId",
    "AdministrationPath": "/administration"
  }
}
```

The API to which I am doing the 'POST' request is working fine for the 'POST' request when invoked directly from Swagger or Postman.
[image: Swagger image]

Please let me know what I should change in ocelot.json file so that the 'POST' request can through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is effectively saying that Ocelot is unable to route requests to

```
POST /api/patient/CreateAppointment
```

In your screenshot, your curl command (which is working) is a request to:

```
POST /api/patient
```

Your `/{everything}` path suffix is telling Ocelot that whatever suffix you call into the gateway with will be present on the downstream service.

My theory is that you have not defined a *CreateAppointment* endpoint operation on your downstream patient service API. Once you define this path on your service, your `/api/patient/{everything}` route mapping should work fine.

Comment: But I have added "/api/patient/{everything}" in reroute. That should take care of it right? It would be difficult to add route in ocelot.json for each and every route. Please suggest how can I deal with this?

Comment: Sorry if not clear. What I am saying is that you are not hitting the create appointment endpoint from swagger UI. If you use postman or curl and try to call /createappointment it will not work